# How will DB2 reading rows while updating in multiple threads application?

Tags: sql, db2

I'd like to know the behavior of DB2 in the following statement in multithreads environment?

```
SELECT * FROM FINAL TABLE 
(
UPDATE USERTABLE.USERS 
SET MAILED = 3 WHERE NOT MAILED = 3 AND STATUS = 2
)
```

This query read all rows which STATUS = 2 and MAILED != 3 and then set MAILED = 3, so next query shouldn't read same rows.

What happens if there're two threads which simultaneously will begin this query? Is it possible that both of them will read same rows and process them? How can I prevent that? I want that until first query won't complete another query won't begin?

Comment: Have you heard about Transaction in DBMS? Read about it.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens if there're two threads which simultaneously will begin this query? Is it possible that both of them will read same rows and process them?

It is not only possible, but unavoidable that concurrent transactions *read* the same data. You can prevent concurrent *updates* by using the [Read Stability isolation level](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0004121.html?lang=en), in which case other transactions will wait until the locks are released. To specify the isolation level, either append `WITH RS` to your statement or issue the statement `SET ISOLATION RS` in your application session.

Comment: Thank you, but concurrent updates for me is less important, I need to prevent concurrent read, how can I achieve this? Is Repeatable Read enough to perform this?

Comment: Like I said, you cannot prevent concurrent reads, unless you introduce an indicator column, which each transaction updates to prevent other transactions from reading the corresponding rows.

Comment: If you're worried about executing the statement in the question from two different applications, the way updates work means that it's going to update (and lock) one set of rows and return them to one application, and a different set to the other.  Well, assuming you're using `RS` or `RR`.  Your bigger problem is going to be that if something causes the application doing the mailing to crash and burn, this design is going to have a terrible time finding out (from just the db) what stuff it mailed out...